# How do I run pentaho data integration transformation from repository?

Tags: pentaho, redhat

I have pentaho data integration repository in postgres database. I want to run the job in this repository from remote server. How can I run this transformation from remote server using pan.sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to copy ./kettle from user directory to server. This directory has repository information. Than:

**./pan.sh -rep=repo_id -user=admin -pass=admin -trans=transformation_name**

**If you are running it form cron then you need to set environment variables!!**

Comment: One note for someone that may come across this in the future is that kitchen.sh would be for running jobs. I mention this because the OP is using job and transformation interchangeably (**"I want to run the job"**) which may lead to confusion.